# Вылетает окно PyQT5 при попытке подтвердить ввод

Tags: python

Пытаюсь создать окно, в которое будет вводится имя пользователя (в дальнейшем по этому имени будет создаваться текстовый файл), но по нажатию на `"Ок"` закрывается даже главное окно (функция `CreateNewUser`)

```
from PyQt5 import * 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import sys
import os

class FirstWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Working time"
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 400
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        #--------Меню программы
        #Менюшка с кнопкой выхода из приложения
        #--------
        self.statusBar()
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu2 = menubar.addMenu('&Users')
        #Exit
        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('./images/web.png'), '&File', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit Application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.exit)
        #List of users
        usersAction = QAction(QIcon('./images/web.png'), '&UserList', self)
        usersAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+U')
        usersAction.triggered.connect(self.getUsersList)
        #CreateUser
        CreateUser = QAction('&CreateNew', self)
        CreateUser.setShortcut('Ctrl+n')
        CreateUser.triggered.connect(self.CreateNewUser)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
        fileMenu2.addAction(usersAction)
        fileMenu2.addAction(CreateUser)
        self.show()

    def getUsersList(self):
        tmpList = os.listdir()
        UsersList = []
        for item in tmpList:
            if item[-3:] == 'txt':
                UsersList.append(item)
        print(UsersList)
    def CreateNewUser(self):
        self.le = QLineEdit(self)
        self.le.move(70, 70)
        self.setWindowTitle("Create new user")
        self.button = QPushButton("show", self)
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'InputDialog', 'Enter new name: ')
        self.show()
        if ok:
            self.le.setText(str(text))
            NewName = self.le.getText()
            f = open(NewName, 'w')
            f.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
                                     "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
                                     QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
            print('window closed')
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FirstWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QLineEdit` не имеет атрибута '**getText**'. Вы видимо хотели использовать `text()`, если вам надо прочитать текст из `QLineEdit`, но мне кажется, что эта строка лишняя.

Я внес некоторые изменения в ваш код, теперь он работает. Обратите внимание на строки, в которые внесены изменения - они помечены.

```
import sys
import os
#from PyQt5 import * 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 


class FirstWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Working time"
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 400
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        #--------Меню программы
        #Менюшка с кнопкой выхода из приложения
        #--------
        self.statusBar()
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu2 = menubar.addMenu('&Users')
        #Exit
        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('./images/web.png'), '&File', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit Application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.exit)
        #List of users
        usersAction = QAction(QIcon('./images/web.png'), '&UserList', self)
        usersAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+U')
        usersAction.triggered.connect(self.getUsersList)
        #CreateUser
        CreateUser = QAction('&CreateNew', self)
        CreateUser.setShortcut('Ctrl+n')
        CreateUser.triggered.connect(self.CreateNewUser)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
        fileMenu2.addAction(usersAction)
        fileMenu2.addAction(CreateUser)
#        self.show()

    def getUsersList(self):
        tmpList = os.listdir()
        UsersList = []
        for item in tmpList:
            if item[-3:] == 'txt':
                UsersList.append(item)
        print(UsersList)

    def CreateNewUser(self):
        self.le = QLineEdit(self)
        self.le.move(70, 70)
        self.setWindowTitle("Create new user")
        self.button = QPushButton("show", self)
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'InputDialog', 'Enter new name: ')
#        self.show()

        print(text, ok)
#        if ok:
        if text:                                          # +++
            self.le.setText(text)                         # (str(text))

#            NewName = self.le.getText()
            NewName = self.le.text()                      # +++     ??? NewName

#            f = open(NewName, 'w')
#            f.close()

            with open('{}.txt'.format(text), 'w') as f:    # +++    + .txt
                pass

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
                                     "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
                                     QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
            print('window closed')
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FirstWindow()
    ex.show()                                             # +++
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо
А что именно вызывало вылет главного окна? Чтобы в будущем не столкнуться с подобной проблемой? Именно попытка использования getText()?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКоверев пожалуйта